# file() VS file_get_contents() which is better? PHP

Tags: php

I just want to know how to improve the speed of the web application I am creating.

I am also open to other suggestions.

fread or file_get_contents??

Comment: file_get_contents() is much better for readable code...

Comment: how do you need the final data? as an array or as a string?

Comment: "what im trying to do is read the file and save the contents. thnx" - you mean `copy()`? :)

Comment: No. Im saving it in the same file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They're unrelated, actually.

`file()` reads the file into an array by parsing [EOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) characters, while `file_get_contents()` actually reads the file contents into a string.

Also, this means you are at the mercy of the server operating system, since Windows EOL is different from Linux EOL (for example).

So, the first one is text-friendly, while the second one binary-friendly.

In short, don't try doing `file('image.png');`

Comment: what im trying to do is read the file and save the contents. thnx

Comment: You should use `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score 3):

[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) — Reads entire file into a string

[file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) — Reads entire file into an array

Use whatever suits your situation best. Do you want to read the file in an array or string?